# Save 'Look up & data detectors' history?

Tags: macos, applescript, trackpad, dictionary

A system gesture I use often when reading is to force press on a word which will pull up a definition and/or wikipedia page of the selected word (referred to as 'Look up & data detectors' in system preferences > trackpad). I'd like to save my history (preferably into a flashcard format) for review.

Anyone know of someone who's accomplished this or which direction to look in?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say you'd *like to save my history*, do you mean a history of just the words you looked up? Or is it you want a copy of the actual definition, a copy of the wikipedia URL, etc? Something else? Also, can you clarify what version of macOS you're running?

Comment: @Monomeeth I had in mind just the words, but more data can't hurt. I'm running 10.12.6

Comment: This is a cool idea. I would go about it by watching for windows of the type *popover* class *_NSPopoverWindow* and extracting and saving the contents to a log. The only comparable thing I've seen was an app hat records screenshots of your desktop every time a window changes and runs OCR on it all so that you can search for anything you've done in the past, in this case instances of "Look Up". I can't for the life of me remember the name of it (actually there were two very similar apps) but I'll comment again when it comes to me.

Comment: Perhaps use an app (is there one?) that monitors touchpad inputs and take a screenshot when force pressing. Then locate the highlighted word (perhaps there is a way?) and run OCR on the portion.

Comment: There must be an easier way than all this OCR business. I checked Activity Monitor and saw a It starts with LookupViewService:

/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.apple.LookupViewService/Data


/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Lookup.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/LookupViewService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/LookupViewService

makes a cached plist file which then vanished:
/Library/Preferences/Logging/.plist-cache.ntgi6M0o


/usr/share/icu/icudt66l.dat - no idea

/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib - sounds fun

then checks my timezone
/private/var/db/analyticsd/events.whitelist

Comment: @MattSephton I'm really interested in the apps you have mentioned. Do you have their names available?

Comment: @JoyJin I was never able to find them again but am certain I saw one on ProductHunt as I made a note of it elsewhere (but without the app name!). I found apps called DejaVideo, RetroClip, Rewind but they don't feature the OCR aspect. I'll keep trying to remember.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to achieve your goal with Automator even though it is a bit slow. Below are the procedures.

1. Create a new 'Quick Action' with Automator.
2. Set 'Workflow receives current' to text.
3. Search 'run javascript' in the search bar, and double click it to create an action. Then paste code below to simulate the lookup keystroke.

   ```
   function run(input, parameters) {
       var se = Application("System Events");
       se.keystroke("d", {using: ["control down", "command down"]});
       return input;
   }
   ```
4. Search 'run shell script' in the search bar, and double click it to create an action. Set 'Pass input' as 'as arguments'. Then paste code below to store text in a file. You can modify the text to be stored however you like. Replace xxxx with your own home directory.

   ```
   timestamp=$(date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
   entry="$timestamp, $1"
   echo $entry >> /Users/xxxx/Library/Logs/lookup.log
   ```
5. Press 'command + s' to save it with a name. Such as 'SuperLookUp'.
6. Open 'system preferences', 'security & privacy', 'privacy', 'Accessibility', click '+' to add applications where you want to use this super lookup function.
7. Open 'system preferences', 'security & privacy', 'privacy', 'Automation', enable the applications where you want to use this super lookup function.
8. Open 'system preferences', 'keyboard', 'shortcuts', 'services', 'text', 'SuperLookUp', then assign a shortcut to trigger this super lookup function. Such as 'shift + command + e'.
9. Now you can use the shortcut 'shift + command + e' to look up a text and store the history in `/Users/xxxx/Library/Logs/lookup.log`.

Note:

1. `/Users/xxxx/Library/Logs/lookup.log` is the only path I find won't throw any permission error.
2. If you encounter any permission issues, it's most likely you have not granted the 'accessibility' and 'automation' to the application. Yeah, you have to do it for EVERY application.
3. You can customise the three finger lookup for touchpad with a third party application to trigger this SuperLookUp.
4. Automator is slow. But It does what you want.
5. I have tested aforementioned method on Safari and Firefox on macOS Monterey 12.4 without any issues. It won't work on the preview  somehow. I reckon text in pdf files are treated as rich text, which needs further investigation. But that is out of scope for now.